# Folders above root in openshift

Tags: git, python-2.7, flask, openshift

This is my first time developing a website on openshift.

I want some resources to be outside the root folder so that for example:-

```
app-user.rhcloud.com/resources/default_bg.jpg
```

should not be accessible but should load when requested by a page in the site.

The question here is that during the git push i notice that default entry point is wsgi.py

If i make a master folder and place wsgi.py inside another folder like:-

```
app_folder
  .
  ...entry_point_folder
  .   .
  .   ...wsgi.py
  .
  ...resources
      .
      ...default_bg.jpg
```

how do i make the entry point to be that wsgi.py file inside 'entry_point_folder' folder.
Will this attempt allow me to prevent direct file access to resources?

I am using python 2.7 and flask.

If I am missing something please tell me about some good reads to cover up that lapse in knowledge.

Comment: How exactly would that image "not be accessible but should load when requested by a page in the site"? What do you expect to gain by making your background image inaccessible to the world? Do you realize that, regardless of your server setup, if an image loads in a web browser it can be copied?

Comment: yes. The image was an example. This is just to learn about openshift. I wanted to restrict the method of access. With the image being displayed in the browser, the site admin controls what the world can see and what it cannot. With unrestricted access one can guess the path and obtain the resource even if it has been removed from the webpages in the site. This was simply a theoretical effort.

Comment: This still isn't clear. When an image is included in a webpage, the browser, running on the user's computer, retrieves the file using standard HTTP. The image virtually *has to be* publicly accessible. There is no difference between viewing an image in a browser and downloading it with `wget`. If you're trying to control access to, for instance, Python source code that's *entirely different*. The browser never requests Python source; access to these files is not required to be (and probably shouldn't be) public. Your server executes code and sends the output to the user's browser.

Comment: so are all .py files hidden from the public by default? ...i guess this is pretty noobish. Are there any other files that are hidden?

Comment: You should probably check out OpenShift's [getting started page](https://www.openshift.com/developers/get-started). There is a section for Python developers.

Comment: Thanks, found it after going through openshift and flask again... :-)